# How can I add a wildcard to my if formula (that also contains an or condition)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column of locations on an Excel file, and some of the locations can be named something like this

[image]

So what I want to do with my formula is say, if the last 3 characters are "IDE" or, if the last 5 characters are "IDE-(and a wildcard) then add a "Y" to the column otherwise add an "N".

I have the following formula, but even though the location is MyLocation IDE-1 it is still giving me an "N" and I'm not sure f what I am doing wrong

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(L1,3)="IDE", RIGHT(L1,5)="IDE-"&"*"),"Y","N")
```

Comment: Functions that supports wildcards are only known to me are AVERAGEIF, AVERAGEIFS
COUNTIF, COUNTIFS, MAXIFS, MINIFS, SUMIF, SUMIFS, VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP, MATCH,
SEARCH. dont know how you are using it

Comment: Thanks! I just googled it and it says that the if function does not support this

Comment: Instead of looking at the last 5, why not disregard the last character and look at the 4 previous to it?

Comment: I came up with this, but it is an ugly formula =IF(ISERROR(OR(RIGHT(A1,3)="IDE",RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-SEARCH("IDE-"&"*",A1)+1)=RIGHT(A1,5))),"N","Y")

Comment: Second that thought of @BigBen Sir using previous 4 can also be achieved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1,{"* IDE","* IDE-?"})),"Y","N")
```

Or, a little less verbose:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"* IDE"&{"","-?"})),"Y","N")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(OR(RIGHT(L1,3)="IDE", IFERROR(SEARCH("IDE-*",RIGHT(L1,5),1),FALSE)),"Y","N")
```

Change your `RIGHT(L1,5)="IDE-"&"*"` to `IFERROR(SEARCH("IDE-*",RIGHT(L1,5),1),FALSE)` . `SEARCH` can use wildcards

[image]